# Python: What is an efficient way to sort a nested array by repeated values?

Tags: python, performance, list, nested, repeat

- `data` is a list, where each entry is a list of floats
- `L` is a range to check whether the first entry of `_` in `data` is equal to and if so store it at that index in `c`

---

```
c = []
d = []
for i in range(L):
    for seq in data:
        if int(seq[0]) == i:
            d.append(seq)
    c.append(d)
    d = []
return c
```

---

```
>>> data = [[4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 67.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 72.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 70.0], [1.0, -0.0, 15.0, 90.0], [3.0, -0.0, 15.0, 75.0], [2.0, -0.0, 15.0, 83.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 74.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 69.0], [4.0, 0.0, 14.0, 61.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 74.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 75.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 67.0], [5.0, 0.0, 14.0, 45.0], [6.0, 0.0, 13.0, 30.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 74.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 55.0], [7.0, 0.0, 13.0, 22.0], [6.0, 0.0, 13.0, 25.0], [1.0, -0.0, 15.0, 83.0], [7.0, 0.0, 13.0, 18.0]]
>>> sort(data,7)
[[], [[1.0, -0.0, 15.0, 90.0], [1.0, -0.0, 15.0, 83.0]], [[2.0, -0.0, 15.0, 83.0]], [[3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 72.0], [3.0, -0.0, 15.0, 75.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 74.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 74.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 75.0], [3.0, 0.0, 15.0, 74.0]], [[4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 67.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 70.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 69.0], [4.0, 0.0, 14.0, 61.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 67.0], [4.0, 0.0, 15.0, 55.0]], [[5.0, 0.0, 14.0, 45.0]], [[6.0, 0.0, 13.0, 30.0], [6.0, 0.0, 13.0, 25.0]]]
```

`len(data)` is on the order of 2 Million
`L` is on the order of 8000.

I need a way to speed this up ideally!

Comment: Can you add some input and expected output as I don't follow your logic? Using things like `_` as variables names that you actually use also does not help

Comment: Just a short hint: The underscore `_` conventionally indicates a *throwaway* variable in iterations. You may want to rename it, as it may confuse others reading your code.

Comment: In any case: you are iterating over `data` over and over again, but you may notice that given an element `seq` of data, if `int(seq[0]) == i` then that element will not match in all other iterations for different values of `i`! You may consider starting with `c = [[] for _ in range(L)]` and then doing: `for el in data: c[int(el)].append(el)`.  The only problem is that if you had values where `int(seq[0]) > L` your code would "ignore" them, while this one gives an `IndexError`.

Comment: Are you trying to *bucket-sort* your float values by their integer typecasts?

Comment: Alternatively: change `c` to be a `defaultdict(list)` and then do: `for seq in data: c[int(seq[0])].append(seq)` this should work independently of the values found in `seq[0]`.

Comment: @jbndlr, yes I believe so. I also added an expected input and output.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks I'll try that and see how it affects runtime

Answer (score 0):

### Optimization attempt

Assuming you want to sort your sublists into *buckets* according to the first value of each sublist.

For simplicity, I use the following to generate random numbers for testing:

```
L = 10
data = [[round(random.random() * 10.0, 2) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)]
```

First about your code, just to make sure that I got your intention correctly.

```
c = []
d = []
for i in range(L): # Loop over all buckets
    for e in data: # Loop over entire data
        if int(e[0]) == i: # If first float of sublist falls into i-th bucket
            d.append(e) # Append entire sublist to current bucket
    c.append(d) # Append current bucket to list of buckets
    d = [] # Reset
```

This is inefficient, because you loop over the full data set for each of your buckets. If you have, as you say, like `8000` buckets and `2 000 000` lists of floats, you will be essentially performing `16 000 000 000` (**16 Billion**) comparisons. Additionally, you completely populate your bucket lists on creation instead of reusing the existing lists in your `data` variable. So this makes as many data reference copies.

Thus, you should think about working with your data's indices, e.g.

```
bidx = [int(e[0]) for e in data] # Calculate bucket indices for all sublists
buck = []
for i in range(L): # Loop over all buckets
    lidx = [k for k, b in enumerate(bidx) if b == i] # Get sublist indices for this bucket
    buck.append([data[l] for l in lidx]) # Collect list references
print(buck)
```

This should result in a single iteration over your data calculating the bucket indices in-place. Then, only one second iteration over all your buckets is performed, where corresponding bucket indices are collected from `bidx` (you *have* to have this double loop, but this may be a bit faster though) -- resulting in `lidx` holding the positions of sublists in `data` that fall into the current bucket. Finally, collect the list references in the bucket's list and store it.

The last step can be costly though, because it contains a lot of reference copying. You should consider storing only the indices in each bucket, not the entire data, e.g.

```
lidx = ...
buck.append(lidx)
```

### However, optimizing performance only in-code with large data has limits.

If your data is large, all linear iterations will be costly. You can try to reduce them as far as possible, but there is a lower cap defined by the data size itself!

If you have to perform more operations of millions of records, you should think about changing to another data representation or format. For example, if you need to perform frequent operations within one script, you may want to think about trees (e.g. b-trees). If you want to store it for further processing, you may want to think about a database with proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Running in Python 3 I get 2 order of magnitude better performance than jbndlr with this algorithm:

```
rl = range(L)   # Generate the range list
buck = [[] for _ in rl]     # Create all the buckets
for seq in data:  # Loop over entire data
    try:
        idx = rl.index(int(seq[0]))   # Find the bucket index
        buck[idx].append(seq)     # Append current data in its bucket
    except ValueError:
        pass    # There is no bucket for that value
```

Comparing the algorithms with:

```
L = 1000
data = [[round(random.random() * 1200.0, 2) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(100000)]
```

I get:

```
yours: 26.66 sec
jbndlr: 6.78 sec
mine: 0.07 sec
```